# Check the continuity and differentiability of $f(x)= \sin^{-1}(\cos x)$ at $x=0$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, derivatives

> Check the continuity and differentiability of  $f(x)= \sin^{-1}(\cos x)$  at $x=0$

This is how I tried to solve the problem:
$$f(x)= \sin^{-1}(\cos x)=???$$

$$\lim_{x \to 0^+}f(x)=\lim_{x \to 0^-}f(x)=f(0)=???$$
Therefore the function is continuous at $x=0$
$$\lim_{x \to 0^+}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=???$$and
$$\lim_{x \to 0^-}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{-x}=???$$

Comment: I need an exact answer with each of the above steps

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In this question it's important to note that $\sin^{-1}(c)$ is (customarily) defined as the unique value of $x \in [-\pi/2,\pi/2]$ such that $\sin x = c$.  In particular, $f(x) = \sin^{-1}(\cos x)$ can never take values outside the range $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$, contradicting the claim in another answer that $f(x) = \pi/2 - x$.

If you graph the function carefully near $x=0$, you'll find it simplifies to $f(x) = \pi/2 - |x|$ for $-\pi \le x \le \pi$.  I think you already know something about whether $|x|$ is differentiable at $x=0$.

Comment: Yes it is not differenatiable but I need to prove it mathematically

Comment: @chndn What is not "mathematical" about the proper use of the fact that $|x|$ is not differentiable at $x=0$?  A proof demands logic, not rote calculation.

Comment: So it is not possible?

Comment: :) There we go, I couldn't derive properly a trigonometric function.. What a beautiful way to begin a Sunday! @chndn Erick's answer is a purely mathematical proof (and elegant with that). Why bother with formulas when a few words can make it clear enough?

Answer (score 5):

Both $\arcsin$ (I prefer this notation to $\sin^{-1}$) and $\cos$ are continuous functions, so it's also their composition, wherever it's defined; since $-1\le\cos x\le 1$ for all real $x$, your function $f$ is continuous on the real line.

Let's compute its derivative:

$$
f'(x)=\arcsin'(\cos x) \cos'x=
-\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\cos^2 x}}\sin x=
-\frac{1}{\lvert\sin x\rvert}\sin x
$$

whenever this expression is defined. So your function is differentiable on all $x$ that are not integer multiples of $\pi$. What about differentiability in $0$? It's the same as in the other points where the above expression is undefined.

We have
$$
\lim_{x\to 0^-}f'(x)=1,\quad \lim_{x\to 0^+}f'(x)=-1
$$
so, by l'Hôpital's theorem the function $f$ is not differentiable in $0$.

What can you deduce from this? Let's limit ourselves to the interval $(0,\pi)$. Here your function has the same derivative as $x\mapsto-x$, so there is $c$ such that $f(x)=-x+c$:
$$
f(\pi/2)=\arcsin\cos\frac{\pi}{2}=\arcsin0=0=-\frac{\pi}{2}+c
$$
so that you can surely write
$$
f(x)=\frac{\pi}{2}-x \quad \text{for }x\in(0,\pi).
$$

For $x\in(-pi,0)$ the situation is similar: your function has the same derivative as $x\mapsto x$, so you can write $f(x)=x+d$:
$$
f(-\pi/2)=\arcsin\cos\left(-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=\arcsin0=0=-\frac{\pi}{2}+d
$$
so that $d=\pi/2$. Therefore
$$
f(x)=\frac{\pi}{2}+x \quad \text{for }x\in(-\pi,0).
$$

You can go on and write an explicit expression for $f$, but observing that it is periodic with period $\pi$ makes this unnecessary. In any case, be very careful, because $\sqrt{1-\cos^2x}=\sin x$ is, in general false; the correct identity is

$$\sqrt{1-\cos^2x}=\lvert\sin x\rvert$$

Comment: Thanks ...... +1 You really deserve something

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: with some precisions following Erick's comment :)

I suppose $x\in[0,\pi]$ so $\cos$ is bijective to $[-1,1]$.
If you use $\cos x = \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-x\right)$, then $\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-x\right)\in[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]$ and you can safely apply $\sin^{-1}$:
$$
f(x) = \frac{\pi}{2}-x
$$
which gives us $f(0^+)=\frac{\pi}{2}$ and
$
\frac{f(x)-f(0^+)}{x} = -1
$.

Now, to get the same with $0^-$, let's assume $x\in[-\pi,0]$. This time $\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-x\right)\in[\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{3\pi}{2}]$ and given that $f(x)=f(-x)$ as a result of being composed with $\cos$, we have:
$$
f(x) = \frac{\pi}{2}+x
$$
which gives us $f(0^-)=\frac{\pi}{2}$ and
$
\frac{f(x)-f(0^-)}{x} = 1
$.

Therefore $f$ is continuous, but not differentiable at $0$ :)

Comment: So it should be differentiable right? But my book says it is not. So are you sure that both my question and your answer has no errors? thnx

Comment: No it is inverse trigonometric function all right. Also can u explain how u found out the continuity and differentiability?

Comment: @chndn Your book is correct, it is not differentiable but for something of a technicality.  Notice that for small negative $x$, $f(x) = \pi/2 + x$ rather than $\pi/2 -x$.

Comment: @chndn The point is that there are many solutions to $\sin x = r$, and $\sin^{-1} r$ is just one of many.  So it is not true in general that $\sin^{-1} ( \sin x) = x$, making your first step invalid for certain $x$.

Comment: @Erick Wong So how do solve it. can u post an answer ... +1

Comment: @ErickWong Thanks a lot :) I was editing again when you posted this comment, how about now?

Comment: @Sh3ljohn Miscalculation for $x<0$.  To see this, note that $f$ is an even function since it is a function of $\cos x$.

Comment: @Sh3ljohn I suggest you plot $\sin^{-1}(\cos x)$ on WolframAlpha and reconcile your formulae with that.

Comment: @ErickWong Thanks a lot for your guidance :) @ chndn Please give the answer to Erick, I couldn't have done it without his comments!